# Is there a source that says that Hashem keeps all halachos of the Torah?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, observance

I am looking for the מקור that Hashem keeps all Halachos of the Torah - if there is one.

Comment: Why might you think there is one?

Comment: How can Hashem *keep* all the Halachos? He is not a physical being so that (for example) He cannot keep Kosher since He does not eat.

Comment: בירושלמי (ר"ה פ"א ה"ג) בנוהג שבעולם מלך ב"ו גוזר גזירה רצה מקיימה רצו אחרים מקיימים אותה אבל הקב"ה אינו כן אלא גוזר גזירה ומקיימה תחילה מ"ט "ושמרו את משמרתי אני ה'" (ויקרא כב:ט) אני הוא ששימרתי מצוותיה של תורה תחילה. א"ר סימון כתיב "מפני שיבה תקום והדרת פני זקן ויראת מאלקיך אני ה'" (ויקרא יט:לב) אני הוא שקיימתי עמוד זקן תחילה (פ' בקרבן העדה דר"ל באברהם אבינו).

Comment: @sabbahillel in Kabbalah it’s explained how in a entirely different sense Hashem fulfills the Mitzvos in a spiritual way. [Maamar Issa B’Midrash Tehillim](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/2317444/jewish/Chapter-5-The-Maamar.htm)

Comment: @sabbahillel  דרך מצותיך - מצות תפילין: עפמ"ש בכהאריז"ל סוד הקב"ה שהוא ז"א מניח תפילין הם ד' מוחי' חו"ב חו"ג הנמשכים לו מאו"א ושרשם מזיווג מזל הח' ונוצר עם מזל הי"ג ונקה, שמשם נמשך האור לאו"א ומהם ע"י נה"י שלהם מתלבשים בגלגלתא דז"א, וע"י קוצי דשערי דמו"ס דא"א היורד מאחוריו ומגיע עד רישא דז"א שמלביש לא"א מכל צדדיו ומכה שם בערפו ובאמצע ששם מוח הדעת המלובש ביסוד אימא (שבה מלובש יסוד אבא שבו דעת דאבא) עי"ז נחלק מוח הדעת לחו"ג ומחמת כח הכאה

Comment: זו יוצאים ונדחים מן מוחי' דז"א הללו שהם א"פ הארה על המצח דז"א בין עיניו ונעשי' שם בחי' מקיפים לפניו ובולטי' לחוץ והן הן התפילין דמארי עלמא, ומה כתיב בהו ומי כעמך ישראל (דה"א י"ז כ"א) לפי שכ"ז נעשה ע"י הנחת תפילין שאנו מניחים על הראש, ותפלה של יד הם ד' מוחי' דנוק' שנמשכים לה מז"א וע"י קוצי דשערי דז"א המכה באחוריו יוצאים ובולטי' במצחא ג"כ והם אצלה תש"ר אך לגבי ז"א נק' תש"י לפי שבעלותה מבי"ע בשחרית עומדת בזרוע שמאלו כנגד לבו וז"ס שימני כחותם על לבך כחותם על זרועך (שה"ש ח' ו') ע"ש בארוכה:

Answer (score 4):

Midrash Rabah (Shemos 30, beginning of Parashas Mishpatim) translation pending…

(מדרש רבה (שמות ל, ר"פ משפטים

הה"ד (שם קמז) מגיד דבריו ליעקב אלו הדברות חוקיו ומשפטיו לישראל אלו המשפטים לפי שאין מדותיו של הקב"ה כמדת ב"ו מדת ב"ו מורה לאחרים לעשות והוא אינו עושה כלום הקב"ה אינו כן אלא מה שהוא עושה הוא אומר לישראל לעשות ולשמור מעשה ברבן גמליאל ור' יהושע ור"א בן עזריה ור' עקיבא שהלכו לרומי ודרשו שם אין דרכיו של הקב"ה כבשר ודם שהוא גוזר גזירה והוא אומר לאחרים לעשות והוא אינו עושה כלום והקב"ה אינו כן היה שם מין אחד אחר שיצאו אמר להם אין דבריכם אלא כזב לא אמרתם אלהים אומר ועושה למה אינו משמר את השבת אמרו לו רשע שבעולם אין אדם רשאי לטלטל בתוך חצירו בשבת א"ל הן אמרו לו העליונים והתחתונים חצירו של הקב"ה שנאמר (ישעיה ו) מלא כל הארץ כבודו ואפילו אדם עובר עבירה אינו מטלטל מלא קומתו א"ל הן אמרו לו כתיב (ירמיה כג) הלא את השמים ואת הארץ אני מלא.

Comment: Very interesting that the midrash addresses the issue of G-d being shomer Shabbos.  I have wondered for a while re: H' commonly causing lightning and starting fires on Shabbos re: the prohibition of לא תבערו אש and had wondered whether the answer lies somehow in the nature of H's melacha (בריאת העולם) being fundamentally different from our melacha (being a function of מלאכת המשכן).

Comment: @EraserX There’s a maamar from the Baal HaTanya that explains just that.  In what sense does Hashem rest on Shabbos, how would the world continue to receive vitality? He explains that on Shabbos the world receives its vitality through the level of thought whereas during the week it’s from Hashem’s speech. That’s why mundane speech is asur on Shabbos whereas thinking of melachah is mutar.